# How can I get Merge to indicate missing values?

Tags: associations

Say I have the following code:

```
Merge[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>}, Identity]
```

The output is:

```
<|"a" -> {1, 2}, "b" -> {2}, "c" -> {3}|>
```

But what I really want is the following:

```
<|"a" -> {1, 2}, "b" -> {2, Missing}, "c" -> {Missing, 3}|>
```

I know how to do it in "longhand," but I am wondering if there is a terse option in `Merge` itself that would accomplish the task.

Comment: By longhand, do you just mean using `Merge @* KeyUnion`?

Comment: Actually, no.  I was mapping the keys of one over the other.  But thanks for teaching me about `KeyUnion`.  That seems to solve the problem.  (On a separate note, Wolfram Language has so many built-in functions that it is really hard to keep on top of the list.)  If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to use [`KeyUnion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyUnion.html), which along with [`KeyIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyIntersection.html), allows for useful customization of what `Merge` should do with missing keys. Its default behavior is pretty much exactly what you were asking for:

```
Merge[KeyUnion[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>}],      
 Identity]    
(* <|"a" -> {1, 2}, "b" -> {2, Missing["KeyAbsent", "b"]}, 
     "c" -> {Missing["KeyAbsent", "c"], 3}|> *)
```

If you want just the bare symbol `Missing` as a sentinel value (which I personally avoid, because [`MissingQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MissingQ.html) doesn't work for that), you can use the optional second argument:

```
Merge[KeyUnion[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>}, 
  Missing &],
 Identity]
(* <|"a" -> {1, 2}, "b" -> {2, Missing}, "c" -> {Missing, 3}|> *)
```

**EDIT:** As [Sjord Smith](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43522/sjoerd-smit) points out in a comment below, you can use `Missing[]` (with empty brackets) as a minimal sentinel value and `MissingQ` will still pick it up:

```
result = Merge[KeyUnion[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>}, 
  Missing[] &],
 Identity]
(* <|"a" -> {1, 2}, "b" -> {2, Missing[]}, "c" -> {Missing[], 3}|> *)

Select[result, FreeQ[_?MissingQ]]
(* <|"a" -> {1, 2}|> *)
```

Comment: I'm just going to point out that `MissingQ[Missing]` is `False`, but `MissingQ[Missing[]]` is `True`. So if you want a bare-bones missing token, just use `Missing[]`, instead of `Missing`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this already has an answer, but I'd like to point out that there is a built-in function that already does this for merging associations with `Identity`:

```
GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>}]
```

> <|"a" -> {1, 2}, "b" -> {2, Missing["KeyAbsent", "b"]},
> "c" -> {Missing["KeyAbsent", "c"], 3}|>

If you want to apply a merging function other than `Identity`, simply map it over the result. Moreover, `AssociationTranspose` is significantly faster than `Merge` for large datasets, so that's also useful to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful to know.